# python os.getenv() don't see any of my custom variables from Jupyter notebook (os x el capitan)

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables, jupyter

I declared several variables in my bash (through ~/.bash_profile) , and they work in bash itself as well as in python started in bash.

Example:

```
export PUIBy="Dropbox/CUSP/1_1_PUI/PUI_Bycicle_Research/"
```

However, when I start Jupyter notebook, `os.environ` dont see any of them, showing some default list of variables (PWD, SUDO_USER, USERNAME, JPY_PARENT_PID, SSH_AUTH_SOCK, SUDO_UID, GIT_PAGER etc)

My sistem is Mac OS El Captain, anaconda ipython 2.7

Comment: Use `export` command to see if the Bash exports are effective before running `python`.

Comment: Most likely bash_profile is not run correctly.

Comment: How are you launching `python`? [If `bash` isn't your default shell, then the login shell won't use it, and `.bash_profile` isn't read for non-login shells](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/10/execution-sequence-for-bash_profile-bashrc-bash_login-profile-and-bash_logout/). If you're launching from a terminal, you can check pretty quickly if the variable was set with `echo $PUIBy`.

Comment: I am using ipython (jupyter). variables are working and echoing in bash itself

Comment: are you doing the __os.getenv('PUIBy')__ from the same shell?

Comment: So everything works in bash itself: python and bash started from console see everything. However, I don't see any of those variables from my Jupyter Notebook

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually this question has nothing to do with Jupyter.  It is more related to how different .bash files are loaded.

To quote from [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51036/what-is-the-difference-between-bash-profile-and-bashrc)

> .bash_profile is executed for login shells, while .bashrc is executed for interactive non-login shells.
>
> When you login (type username and password) via console, either sitting at the machine, or remotely via ssh: .bash_profile is executed to configure your shell before the initial command prompt.

Because you put your variables into .bash_profile it is only available in terminal shells but not in non-interactive shell.

Jupyter-notebook is a web application, even though it runs on your local machine and you access it from local machine (in most cases).  Each time you open a notebook it launches a kernel in its own non-interactive shell.  So if you want environment variables to be visible from the shell, put them into `.bashrc` file, not `.bash_profile`

Also, to view which variables are set,  use `!export` command in your Jupyter notebook

Comment: Traditionally (which is to say: about 30 years ago), when you first logged into your OS it would start a login shell as the parent process to everything else you used in the session, so environment variables set by the login shell would be inherited by other processes that started interactive, non-login shells. So back in the day, setting environment variables only in `.bash_profile` and not in `.bashrc` was correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try `env` instead of `export`

eg:

`env PUIBy="Dropbox/CUSP/1_1_PUI/PUI_Bycicle_Research/" jupyter notebook`

Source: [link](https://www.howmovileworks.com/devel/pass-environment-variables-jupyter-notebook/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually if I set environment variables using a %%bash Jupyter cell and then try to read them back using os.getenv() I dont see them.

If I set them in python using os.setenv, then echo them using %%bash and echo $variablename they have been set correctly.

macOS 15 running jupyter notebook launched from zsh (dont think this makes a difference)

So there appears to be some inconsistent behaviour